# R Spatial Lag Model won't run

Tags: r

I am not sure why the code won't run even though I clearly have the neighborhood list, but yet it still shows the error:

> Error: No neighbourhood list

Packages: spdep

```
#making new neighbors list
n_ces_nb_queen <- st_contiguity(CES_LA_new)

n_ces_queen_W <- st_weights(
  nb = n_ces_nb_queen, 
  style = "W")


slm_fit <- lagsarlm(
  formula = Asthma ~ Ozone + PM2_5 + DieselPM + Tox_Rel + Traffic,  
  data = CES_LA_new,
  listw = n_ces_queen_W)
```

Comment: Where does `st_contiguity` come from? Its not in `spdep`.

Comment: It comes from sfdep

Answer (score 1):

This object:

```
n_ces_queen_W <- st_weights(
  nb = n_ces_nb_queen, 
  style = "W")
```

is not the right thing to be passed as the `listw` argument. See the help for `st_weights` for example.

Use `nb2listw` instead to create a `listw` from your `nb` object:

```
slm_fit <- lagsarlm(
  formula = Asthma ~ Ozone + PM2_5 + DieselPM + Tox_Rel + Traffic,  
  data = CES_LA_new,
  listw = nb2listw(n_ces_nb_queen, style="W"))
```